# How to get the value of x in an expoetial equation in R

Tags: r, exponential

I have the following equation and I want to get the value of x.

```html
(1/(1+exp(-(0.1348*x +  64.7027))))+ (x-70)=0
```

I try library(nleqslv), but I was unsuccessful to get x

Comment: The parenthesis are wrong. Correct, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function `f`:

```
f <- function(x) 1/(1+exp(-(0.1348*x + 64.7027))) + (x - 70)
```

In order to see where a root might fall, plot the function, trying several limits.

```
curve(f, from = 0, to = 100)
```

The one above has end points of opposite signs, so it's a job for `uniroot`.

```
uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 100))
#$root
#[1] 69
#
#$f.root
#[1] 0
#
#$iter
#[1] 1
#
#$init.it
#[1] NA
#
#$estim.prec
#[1] 69
```

In order to have the value of the root, try any of the two ways below.

```
uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 100))$root
#[1] 69

y <- uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 100))
y$root
#[1] 69
```

Comment: Thanks, what is x? then

Comment: It's `uniroot(etc)$root`. You can assign `y <- uniroot(.)` and then `x <- y$root`.

Comment: @user1946911 I have just recopied the expression in the question and rerun the code, the result is *exactly* the same. Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: You can reverse the sign of `x` in the function or define a new `g <- function(x) f(-x)`. is this what you are talking about? But then you would need `uniroot(g, interval = c(-100, 0))$root`.